# How can a NumPy array of booleans be used to remove/filter rows of another NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have one NumPy array like this:

```
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

I want to use this array to filter the rows of another array like this:

```
array([[-0.45556594,  0.46623859],
       [-1.80758847, -0.08109728],
       [-0.9792373 , -0.15958186],
       [ 4.58101272, -0.02224513],
       [-1.64387422, -0.03813   ],
       [-1.8175146 , -0.07419429],
       [-1.15527867, -0.1074057 ],
       [-1.48261467, -0.00875623],
       [ 2.23701103,  0.67834847],
       [ 1.45440669, -0.62921477],
       [-1.13694557,  0.07002631],
       [ 1.0645533 ,  0.21917462],
       [-0.03102173,  0.18059074],
       [-1.16885461, -0.06968157],
       [-0.51789417, -0.05855351],
       [ 4.23881128, -0.30072904],
       [-1.37940507, -0.06478938]])
```

Applying the filter would result in the following array, with just the first three rows:

```
array([[-0.45556594,  0.46623859],
       [-1.80758847, -0.08109728],
       [-0.9792373 , -0.15958186]])
```

How can this be done? When I attempt to do something like `B[A]`, where `A` is the filter array and `B` is the other one, I get only the first column.

Comment: Use `1D` version of `A` : `B[A.ravel()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select entire rows, so you will want a 1 dimensional array to use to select. As mentioned in comments you can use [`numpy.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to straighten out your bool array and apply it to `b` with:

```
b[a.ravel()]
```

You can also explicitly select the first column of `a` and apply it to `b` with:

```
b[a[:, 0]])
```

**Test Code:**

```
a = np.array(
    [[ True],
     [ True],
     [ True],
     [False],
     [False],
     [False]], dtype=bool)

b = np.array(
    [[-0.45556594,  0.46623859],
     [-1.80758847, -0.08109728],
     [-0.9792373 , -0.15958186],
     [ 4.58101272, -0.02224513],
     [-1.64387422, -0.03813   ],
     [-1.37940507, -0.06478938]])

print(b[a.ravel()])
print(b[a[:, 0]])
```

**Results:**

```
[[-0.45556594  0.46623859]
 [-1.80758847 -0.08109728]
 [-0.9792373  -0.15958186]]

[[-0.45556594  0.46623859]
 [-1.80758847 -0.08109728]
 [-0.9792373  -0.15958186]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use np.where to find eligible row indexes:

```
b[np.where(a)[0]]
```